# How to plot real-time position on the screen? - Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have succeeded to determine the walking direction and the distance of a person.

I then wish to plot his or her position on the screen.

How may I do that?

I understand the question may not be that specific, but what I wish to get from you guys are just some ideas.

e.g. which section should I read in the Android Development website or which external library should I import to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use googles LocationClient to get location updates. On every update get the lat and long of the position provided.
You can use Location Client along side google maps to plot location data. Every update you will just remove your marker and place it at the new location. Note you do not have to remove you marker. Then you will have a plot of the locations that you were at. I have seen trail programs that use this to plot hiking paths.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html

There is also a locationmanager that will let you work a little more with the location providers.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Here is an example program on the android dev site.
http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking to plot this data in a graph. I would highly suggest using AndroidPlot (http://androidplot.com/) from here you can download their sample code to make a simple graph.

If you are looking to then to then show the person how far they went and for how long you can plot this data pretty easily in a graph.

If you really wish to show this data on a map then you do not want to use AndroidPlot.

Comment: no i dun want to plot the data. i want to plot the person's PATH

Comment: I updated your tags for using maps. AndroidPlot (which is what you had tagged) is used for plotting data in a graph. Best of luck.